# Can I detect whether autoplay of audio was allowed in Chrome?

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, audio

Chrome blocks autoplayed audio by default, but if the user loads the page by following a link from another page on the same domain, autoplay is allowed.

Can I detect this condition from within Flutter?  I'd like to do something like

```
build(context) {
  if (AUTOPLAY_PREVENTED)
    return SplashScreenToClickToStartTheGame(); // click then allows audio to be played
  else
    return TheGame(); // will autoplay audio
}
```

so that if someone navigates to my game from my own domain they get a nicer experience, not having to jump through the "Click To Play" screen.